# Reusing or creating new Store - ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have several stores in my application. They are not created until I load my grid which should call store.load() function. So some components may have a need of stores that are still not created. I am using this function to fix this problem:

```
getOrCreateStore: function(storeId, className){
    return (Ext.getStore(storeId) == undefined) ? Ext.create(className) : Ext.getStore(storeId);
},
```

So each time component has a need of specific store, I call if created or create it if it doesn't exist.

Is there a better way create the stores so that I don't have to manually do it? Are there some configurations I have missed to set up in my ExtJS 4 application regarding creation of stores?

Why I use the above fix is that grids stay empty if the store is not actually created first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.StoreManager

- You are not giving the store a `storeId` when creating it.
- Your ternary can also be condensed into a `||` operation.

**Code**

```
getOrCreateStore: function(storeId, className){
    return Ext.getStore(storeId) || Ext.create(className, {storeId: storeId});
}
```

**Side Note**:
I consider most Ext's managers to be bad practice. They are nothing more than glorified global variables. I prefer to pass around the stores where they're needed rather than resorting to adding them to global state. However, I do understand that this makes programming easier in some cases, and that if you want this lazy loading of stores (which I'm not sure will really benefit you much), this is the way to go. I'm just warning you that it tends to make maintenance and unit testing harder.

Comment: ok. So when do I create my stores so that I don't have problm testing later? In launch function?

Comment: @Vlad Unfortunately, it's hard to explain this without a thorough understanding of your code and how you write unit tests. It's common knowledge that global variables make testing harder and cause tight coupling between components and the environment, making it harder to test in units. I suggest you try to write a unit test and make sure you can test your components in isolation. I just wanted to remind you that the managers are nothing more than global containers for stores and that you should be as careful as you are with any other global variables you create.

Comment: Well there wasn't actually a problem. The thing was, grids stayed empty, because stores weren't created. And also using line like this, store: 'store.path.name' didn't load the data either.

Comment: @Vlad I'm not sure what you mean, the problem was the you were never actually creating a store with a `storeId`. Now it should be creating it and the grid does have a store (so it displays data).

Comment: I was testing a bit and I got to a case with two grids using same store. One displayed on app start shows data properly with store: 'storepath' option. The second grid is displayed in a window(shown after button click) and will show data only if data was loaded in the first grid. I am confused about this. That is why I don't know what am I talking about. I am also learning ExtJS4 so its still foggy for me.